# How to implement full text search in amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: c#, search, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on S3 in which i have large amount of text,pdf,doc files.each files has a different name.
I want to search some text within a that files .

For the example, I have a files as per below :

1. abc/myfolder/abac.txt
2. abc/myfolder/abacpfd.pdf
3. abc/myfolder/abacpfd.doc

& I want to search text like "I am human" in the above files. if text contains in that files then return file name

How to achieve this ? Is it even possible with c# ?

Comment: do you have any other type of files other than txt, pdf, doc?

Comment: @MihirDave No i dont have

Comment: And approximately at which, frequency search will be triggered? E.g 5 times in a minute or once a hour

Comment: Its depends on users if multiple user want to search at a time so counts goes to 20 to 50 per second .

Comment: Okay, and how big your files are? and Approx the total size of all files

Comment: single file size is around 10 kb to 5 mb

Comment: how many files?

Comment: Unlimited . files count are not fixed

Comment: This might help https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-a-document-search-bot-using-amazon-lex-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not provide any services that relate to the content of objects.

You will need to run some form of software that scans and indexes the content of the S3 files (eg Elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial which uses Tika (for PDF OCR) and OpenSearch (for search engine) to search the contents of PDF files within an S3 bucket:

```
import boto3
from tika import parser
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch
from config import *
import sys


# opensearch object
os = OpenSearch(opensearch_uri)

s3_file_name="prescription.pdf"
bucket_name="mixpeek-demo"


def download_file():
    """Download the file
    :param str s3_file_name: name of s3 file
    :param str bucket_name: bucket name of where the s3 file is stored
    """

    # s3 boto3 client instantiation
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # open in memory
    with open(s3_file_name, 'wb') as file:
        s3_client.download_fileobj(
            bucket_name,
            s3_file_name,
            file
        )
        print("file downloaded")
        # parse the file
        parsed_pdf_content = parser.from_file(s3_file_name)['content']
        print("file contents extracted")
        # insert parsed pdf content into elasticsearch
        insert_into_search_engine(s3_file_name, parsed_pdf_content)
        print("file contents inserted into search engine")


def insert_into_search_engine(s3_file_name, parsed_pdf_content):
    """Download the file
    :param str s3_file_name: name of s3 file
    :param str parsed_pdf_content: extracted contents of PDF file
    """
    doc = {
        "filename": s3_file_name,
        "parsed_pdf_content": parsed_pdf_content
    }
    # insert
    resp = os.index(
        index = index_name,
        body = doc,
        id = 1,
        refresh = True
    )
    print('\nAdding document:')
    print(resp)


def create_index():
    """Create the index
    """
    index_body = {
        'settings': {
            'index': {
                'number_of_shards': 1
            }
        }
    }
    response = os.indices.create(index_name, body=index_body)
    print('\nCreating index:')
    print(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

full tutorial: https://medium.com/@mixpeek/search-text-from-pdf-files-stored-in-an-s3-bucket-2f10947eebd3

Corresponding github repo: https://github.com/mixpeek/pdf-search-s3

Answer (score -1):

Exactly, I had this problem, but somehow I had solved it without using a search approach. If I couldn't find a solution, I was going to try this open source project: [filestash](https://github.com/mickael-kerjean/filestash)

Comment: Ferhat, you got any chance to try Filestash?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Kerem. But I can say that as I remember (not clear so you have to check more detailed) it is not a programatic solution for full text search. I mean there is no sdk or api for it. I was going to use it for a debugging issue in my local. We were suspecting some miss-content files.